# For which $\alpha$ $f(x,y,z)= \frac{\ln(1+x^2y^4z^6)}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\alpha}}$ is differentiable?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

For what values of $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ the function

$$f(x,y,z)= \frac{\ln(1+x^2y^4z^6)}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\alpha}}$$

is differentiable? for which she is not?

I tried to use the definition of differentiability, I tried to find the differential but I could not.

Anyone have any ideas where to start?

Comment: That function really looks very, very ugly. I'm afraid you'll have to go by the definition and for that you shall need the partial derivatives of first order...and those are ugly as they are not symmetric wrt $\;x,\,y,\,z\;$ ...

Comment: [Here’s](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+ln%281%2Bx%C2%B2+y%5E4+z%5E6%29%2F%28x%C2%B2+%2By%C2%B2%2B+z%5E2%29%5E%CE%B1) you’re answer.